# Google Crawling: Now parsing JavaScript results?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML5 web site that simply displays my business card. The text on this "business card" is filled in via JavaScript.

The HTML markup for my business card page looks like:

```
<body>
    <div id="card">
        <name />
        <title />
        <email />
        <phone />
    </div>
</body>
```

When the DOM is ready, these `<name>`, `<title>`, etc. elements are replaced with actual text using JavaScript.

The point of this was actually to prevent search engines from caching and indexing this private contact information of mine.

There is no meta description tag for the page at the moment.

When I type my card page's URL into Google, the results listing shows my name, title, email, etc.

The only way this is possible is if the spider that Google uses to index my page loads the JavaScript and *then* takes a snapshot of the document.

I didn't think Google's crawler parsed JavaScript.

What can I do to put this private information on the web and not have it publically indexed by Google?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Google and potentially any other web crawler to NOT index your webpage, you should use the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

My guess is, Google downloads your page (for cache purposes) and then index it. By which time, the javascript in the page would have filled in your details. (This could be very wrong :D)

Now that is actually indexed by Google, you can [request it to be deleted](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734)